# Show deep field source in Api Platforms Admin list

Tags: javascript, react-admin, api-platform.com

I am using the newest Api Platform Admin component and I am trying to show on the `Ingredients` list a name of `Category` instead of it's API IRI. As you can see below `Category.name` is empty.
[image: Current state of my List in Admin Panel]

I've List defined:

```js
const ingredientsList = props => (
    <ListGuesser {...props}>
        <FieldGuesser source="name" />
        <FieldGuesser source="category" />
        <TextField source="category.name" />
        <FieldGuesser source="description" />
    </ListGuesser>
);
```

When I look at my Browser Network card I see a reponse from my API like below.

```js
{
   "@context":"\/api\/contexts\/Ingredient",
   "@id":"\/api\/ingredients",
   "@type":"hydra:Collection",
   "hydra:member":[
      {
         "@id":"\/api\/ingredients\/1",
         "@type":"Ingredient",
         "name":"Orange",
         "category":{
            "@id":"\/api\/ingredient_categories\/1",
            "@type":"IngredientCategory",
            "name":"fruits"
         },
         "description":"Orange."
      }
   ],
   "hydra:totalItems":1
}
```

But when I do a `console.log` in custom-defined `MyTextField` that's based on "[*Writing your own component*](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html)" part of React-admin documentation in my Console I see:

```js
{
   "@id":"/api/ingredients/1",
   "@type":"Ingredient",
   "name":"Orange",
   "category":"/api/ingredient_categories/1",
   "description":"Orange.",
   "id":"/api/ingredients/1"
}
```

What's going on here? Why the object in `console.log` is different and how to show `Category` name instead of IRI in the list?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display subresource in react-admin you need to use `<ReferenceField>` https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html